# Memory Tracker in C++ going into infinite loop during vector initialization

Tags: c++, windows, new-operator

I am trying to write memory tracker in C++ by overloading `new` and `delete` operator. But it is going into loop and calling `new` again and again. Following is my code.

```
#ifndef MEMORY_TRACKER_H_
#define MEMORY_TRACKER_H_

#pragma warning( disable : 4290 )
#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <DbgHelp.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


static const int MAX_TRACES     = 62;
static const int MAX_LENGTH     = 256;
static const int BUFFER_LENGTH  = (sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(wchar_t) + sizeof(ULONG64) - 1) / sizeof(ULONG64);
static bool SYSTEM_INITIALIZED  = false;

typedef struct record_t {
    std::string symbol;
    std::string address;
    std::string filename;
    std::string linenumber;
} record;

typedef std::vector<record>              record_vec_t;
typedef std::pair<size_t, record_vec_t>  record_entry_t;
typedef std::map<size_t, record_entry_t> memory_record_t;

memory_record_t gMemoryRecord;

static record_vec_t GetCallStackDetails(const void* const* trace, int count ) {
    record_vec_t callStackVector;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        ULONG64 buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        DWORD_PTR frame           = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(trace[i]);
        DWORD64 sym_displacement  = 0;
        PSYMBOL_INFO symbol       = reinterpret_cast<PSYMBOL_INFO>(&buffer[0]);
        symbol->SizeOfStruct      = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        symbol->MaxNameLen        = MAX_LENGTH;
        BOOL has_symbol           = SymFromAddr(GetCurrentProcess(), frame, &sym_displacement, symbol);
        DWORD line_displacement   = 0;
        IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line      = {};
        line.SizeOfStruct         = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);
        BOOL has_line             = SymGetLineFromAddr64(GetCurrentProcess(), frame, &line_displacement, &line);

        record curr_rec;
        curr_rec.symbol = "(No Symbol)";

        std::stringstream formatter;        
        if (has_symbol) {
            curr_rec.symbol = symbol->Name;
            formatter.clear();
            formatter << " [0x" << trace[i] << "+" << sym_displacement << "]";     
            curr_rec.address = formatter.str();
        } else {
            formatter.clear();
            formatter << " [0x" << trace[i] << "]";
            curr_rec.address = formatter.str();
        }
        if (has_line) {
            formatter.clear();
            formatter << line.FileName;
            curr_rec.filename = formatter.str();

            formatter.clear();
            formatter << line.LineNumber;
            curr_rec.filename = formatter.str();
        }
        callStackVector.push_back(curr_rec);
    }
    return callStackVector;
}

static void addRecord(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    if ( SYSTEM_INITIALIZED == false ) {
        SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS | SYMOPT_UNDNAME | SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);
        if (SymInitialize(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, TRUE)) {
            SYSTEM_INITIALIZED = true;
        } else {
            SYSTEM_INITIALIZED = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    void* trace[MAX_TRACES];

    int count            = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, MAX_TRACES , trace, NULL);
    record_vec_t record  = GetCallStackDetails( trace, count);
    record_entry_t entry = std::make_pair( size, record);

    gMemoryRecord.insert(std::make_pair((size_t)ptr, entry));
}

static void deleteRecord(void *ptr ) {
    memory_record_t::iterator itr = gMemoryRecord.find((size_t)ptr);
    if ( itr != gMemoryRecord.end()) {
        gMemoryRecord.erase(itr);
    }
}

void dumpUnfreedMemory() {
    for ( memory_record_t::iterator itr = gMemoryRecord.begin(); itr != gMemoryRecord.end(); ++itr ) {
    }
}

// Overloading new operator
void* operator new ( size_t size ) throw ( std::bad_alloc ) {
    std::cout << " Overloaded new is called " << std::endl;
    void *ptr = (void *)malloc(size);
    addRecord(ptr, size);   

    return ptr;
}

// Overloading delete Operator
void operator delete ( void* ptr ) throw () { 
    std::cout << " Overloaded delete  is called " << std::endl;
    deleteRecord(ptr);
    free ( ptr );
}

#endif
```

following is the test file

```
#include "MemoryTracker.h"
int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    int *ptr = new int;
    return 0;
}
```

it is going into loop on call of `GetCallStackDetails`, platform is `windows`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overloading the global `operator new`, and `std::vector<record>` uses the default allocator, which calls `operator new` to allocate the memory.  Which then calls your GetCallStack, which allocates a new vector ....

One solution is to use a custom allocator in your vector, which pulls from a separate pool of memory, so that it doesn't call your GetCallStack.

Comment: Thanks, how do i specify custom allocator so that it calls std::new operator

Comment: The problem is that you have just replaced `operator new`, so that's the one it will call. As will `std::map`, `std::string`, and possibly also `std::stringstream`. You just cannot use high-level features when implementing low-level features. Consider if you *really* have to implement the global operator, or if you can create `operator new`'s just for the classes you want to track.

Comment: Thanks Dave S, I understood the issue and removed the entire use STL in my code.
Here is the link [Finding Memory leak in C++ Application on Windows](http://avdongre.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/finding-memory-leak-in-c-application-on-windows/)